# Navigation pattern or library in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, wpf-4.0

I am looking into implementing a WPF app using the MVVM pattern and looking to create the navigation framework for the application. The application window has a main view and a navigation bar. The application loads views into the content area of the mainview. From here you can navigate into subscreens that might bring up dialogs or to other views.

I need to keep a navigation journal of the app per user session and let them to do quick user switching, where the user finds the screens as he or she left them.

I would like to refrain from reinventing the wheel and planning to use some sort of libraries, if possible. Is there a library exists for WPF that would help me to implement the above mentioned features? All suggestions and samples are welcome. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) library has a navigation framework, among other things.
You can have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) at how its navigation framework works.